# A bug that falls in noodles

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, bugs

If a small <sub>non-poisonous</sub> bug jumps into a pot of noodles cooking, instantly dying because of the boiling water, and then is scooped out right away is there a problem with either the noodles or the spoon, technically speaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike meat and milk, bugs don't "contaminate" the soup. We don't eat bugs but the soup itself doesn't get spoiled if the bug is removed. Therefore, if one is sure the bug is completely removed, the soup can be eaten.

See detailed halachot of bugs in food [here at dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2015/04/12/parashas-shemini-halachos-of-bugs-in-food/)

> For instance, if a gnat falls into a pot of potatoes and gets lost
>   therein, the potatoes may not be eaten unless one ensures (by cleaning
>   off each potato) that the gnat is not present in the food he is
>   putting into his mouth. Similarly, **if the gnat falls into a pot of
>   soup, the soup will need to be strained through a fine strainer, to
>   ensure that the gnat is not in the soup, before it may be eaten
>   ([Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De’ah 100:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.100.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))**.

Comment: Unless the milk or meat harms the flavor of the dish (of the bug helps the flavor of the dish). It has nothing to do with the nature of the prohibition on meat, milk, or bugs.

Comment: But a bug is different. As you know, even if it was flavourless, a bug is a *beriah* and doesn't get annuled. If you don't find, no matter what the volume is, the dish is forbidden

Comment: a bug that's a biryah is as bad as meat that's a biryah. Your answer implied they are different in terms of ability to contaminate, which is seemingly just about Taam, when again they have the same exact rules.